# Alternatives for Javascript eval

Tags: javascript, firefox, eval, security

Mozilla's [Content Security Policy](http://people.mozilla.com/~bsterne/content-security-policy/details.html) disallows the use of javascript eval function as well as inline scripts. They claim that all instances of eval can be replaced by another (hopefully safer) function. I agree in most scenarios, Javascript eval can be replaced, but I'm not sure whether the replacement is possible for every case.

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a generic way to replace every javascript eval function? (doesn't have to be safe)
2. Is there a case where the Javascript eval cannot be replaced?

Comment: Please post an example, where you aren't sure if you can replace it. Otherwise it's a bit hard to help you.

Comment: well, the problem is, I cannot come up with an example where I cannot replace. However, I also cannot come up with a generic way of replacing eval (it's different for every case).

Comment: @Tony: Do you have a real-world use case, or are you just interested to see if a universal transformation from `eval` to some other language construct exists?

Comment: Mozilla allows for `eval` to work. As of Aug 2018.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most common uses which can be substituted are the following ones. I would certainly use these first.

1. Accessing dynamic properties

   Do use: `obj[keyAsVariable]`

   Don't use `eval('obj.' + keyAsVariable)`
2. Parsing JSON

   Do use `JSON.parse(data)`

   Don't use `eval('(' + data + ')')`
3. Calculating user input

   Do use a certain [library](http://zaach.github.com/jison/)

   Don't use `eval(input)`

If really necessary, you can also send the script to a server which simply echoes it back, and you can request it as a script tag. It won't use `eval` but still execute it. It isn't safe as it's sent twice over the Internet.

```
var s = document.createElement('script')
s.src = 'request_script?data=' + data;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

`request_script` could be a file implemented in PHP, like the following. Again, it's bad practice but is a generic way of circumventing `eval`.

```
<?
echo $_GET['data'];
?>
```

You could say that this also automatically answers your second question with 'no'.

Comment: thanks, the request script method is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @pimvdb No need to bounce it to a server. Check my added answer for an altenative to that suggestion...

Answer (score 4):

### Load as script using a Blob

Instead of using `eval` you can also use a `Blob` and load the code as if it was an external `js` file:
To ensure that functions or variables that are inside the code that you are loading are available you need to use a `callback` method that will be triggered `onload` event.

```
var code = "console.log('hello world');";

// With eval:
eval(code);

// With a blob:
var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'text/javascript'});
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );

function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Add a the script tag to the head
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Bind the callback (depends on browser compatibility).
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Load the script
    head.appendChild(script);
}

// Any variables or methods inside the code will be on callback.
loadScript(url, callback);
```

**Note** *Be aware that the danger for code injection is similar to eval.*

Comment: it's not duplicate

Comment: Super! What needs to be modified if  `code` has to receive an argument and it has a return value?

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the java script within a function call similar to JSONP and then dynamically create a script tag to load that.

Comment: sorry can you explain this a bit more? If I want to run: eval(document.cookie= 'some user input'); How do you replace this with a javascript function call without using eval?

Comment: So if the code you were trying to get executed was `var test = "hello world";` you could convert that into `function go() { var test = "hello world" }` then you you would dynamically generate a script tag to load that code which would evaluate

Comment: I thought of this too, but does this work for every case?