# Alternative to eval() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, eval

I work mainly with javascript, Jquery, knockout, etc

The thing that attracted eval() to me is

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
eval("a+b");
//Gives me output 15
```

Note: I work in cases where the value of `a` and `b` changes dynamically

In my work I'm dealing with a lot of dynamic objects from json, knockout, etc. So eval solves most of my problems. 
But as I read I found there are so many issues with eval() like slowing down etc.

I searched a lot and haven't found any substitute for eval() when i have to evaluate equation obtaining as string into equation as object.

Can anyone suggest a plugin or function alternative to eval() keeping in mind the example i have given above

**Problem:**

*I'm creating a Table from Json data using knockout mapping. So that what ever the format of json is the table is generated. I also calculate some field using knockout computed.
Right now I use hard-coded*

```
self.Salary = ko.computed(function(){ return self.salaryEqn() && eval(self.salaryEqn()).toFixed(2); })
self.salaryEqn(salEqnTxt);
```

*I want to execute these equations dynamic. I can create it dynamicaly as string but to eval them is the issue I'm facing.*

**I want solution for**

Is there a way to calculate a formula stored in a string in JavaScript without using eval?

Like a formula

```
 "self.Salary = ko.computed(function(){ return self.salaryEqn() && eval(self.salaryEqn()).toFixed(2); })"
```

Comment: It won't work for your example, but if what you need is `to evaluate equation obtaining as string into equation as object.` then you could use `JSON.parse`

Comment: In general you should avoid using eval() whenever possible. Check the below link for the problem you face while using eval(). http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Problems%20with%20Evals **UPDATE:** Check this [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029888/what-are-the-alternatives-to-eval-in-javascript?rq=1) answer for alternative of eval in javascript.

Comment: `a + b` gives you `15` without having to represent it as a string and then evaling it.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi will that also give the same result as eval("a+b")

Comment: @Quentin I work with cases where the values of a and b changes dynamicaly

Comment: @Okky — The trouble is that you've simplified your problem so much we can't tell what it is. Your question is "How can I solve X, which can be solved by eval, without using eval?". We don't have enough information to understand what X is.

Comment: Can you specify the problems you're facing exactly? You can always use or create a formula parser, but you would face the same performance issues than when using eval().

Comment: @Okky you might want to specify, which kinds of expressions do you wish to evaluate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Javascript is a very flexible language in this regard. There are very *very* few cases where `eval()` is the right answer to any given question, and it certainly isn't necessary here.

If your `a` and `b` variables are part of an object, you can access them with string subscripts:

ie `myobj.a` could also be referenced as `myobj['a']`.

From that, you can use a variable for the subscript, and thus you can reference any element in `myobj` dynamically -- ie:

```
var myobj = {a : 5, b : 10};

var dynamicProperty1 = 'a';
var dynamicProperty2 = 'b';

//gives 15.
alert( myobj[dynamicProperty1] + myobj[dynamicProperty2] );
```

No `eval()` required. You can build the `dynamicProperty` strings however you wish, so there's virtually infinite flexibility.

If your `a` and `b` variables are globals, JS globals in the browser are actually children of the `window` object, so you can still use this technique even with globals.

ie your global variable `a` could also be accessed via `window.a` or `window['a']`, with the latter option allowing you to do the same `dynamicProperty` trick described above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

do you mean that you want to calculate an equation that you can't know until you've received it?

if so see [Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval) .

### **in short:**

eval CAN be used sometimes, but only if the equation string comes from a trusted source, and there you need something like **evaluating dynamic equations**.

Answer (score 2):

maybe using `window['var' + num]` might be more useful for you. i don't quite understand your question sorry.

Comment: PLEASE do not the window to store variables. PLEASE. Instead use `obj = Object.create(null); obj.a = "value1"; obj.b = " then two"; altert(obj.a +  obj.b); // will alert "value1 then two"`;

Comment: except that `obj = ...` is exactly the same than `var obj = ...` or `window['obj'] = ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you can collect them under an object like `root = {a: 1, b: 2}`, then

```
Object.observe(root, function(newValues) { 
    res = newValues.object.a + newValues.object.b;
});
```

can keep your `res` variable up to date whenever the `a` or `b` changes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do dynamic equations created by a user.

For example it could be 'a+b+c' or 'dog+cat', and you don't know.

The best way to handle user-input equations like that is to parse the text into tokens and then translate the tokens into values/operands.

That's a lot of work, but there are pre-rolled solutions.  For example, [math.js](http://mathjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Check more alternatives to `eval` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2029888/1697459) and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7127652/1697459) which both might be considered a duplicate...

I understand this is a link only answer, but it will for sure be helpful to others searching for alteratives to `eval`.