# Request method via string

Tags: javascript

I got this as string: `app.model('Categories').findAll()`.
When I run this 'command' it returns something. How am I able to get the result by running this string?

Thanks

ps, sorry for the bad explanation :S

Answer (score -1):

I've got it!

`eval()` is the solution.

So run `console.log(eval(app.model('Categories').findAll()))` :)

Comment: eval is usually a bad solution, though :)

Comment: @kuroineko What would be an alternative to `eval()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037033/alternative-to-eval-javascript Any how in your case you probably get an expression as result. Can you please specify what string you get from `app.model('Categories').findAll()`

Comment: `app.model('Categories').findAll()` is the string itself. It will return an array with objects. The idea is to simulate something like https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat