# Angular 2, Error in inline template using eval() function

Tags: javascript, angular, eval

```
<li *ngFor="let pdfifRecord of pdf.ifRecord;let i=index">
                    <p>{{eval(pdfifRecord.labelMsg)}}</p>
</li>
```

I want to display the result of eval.

But getting an error

> Error in inline template caused by: self.parent.parent.parent.context.eval is not a function.

But the same working in my .ts file 
eg:
`console.log(eval("GECM_IFL_ATTENTION_NEEDED_ITIQ"));`

Comment: You should NEVER use `eval()`. NEVER. It screws up scope and opens security holes in your application.

Comment: *EVAL is EVIL*.. why you want eval to be work on template expression, it would be security threat..

Comment: any replacement for the function?

Comment: i hvae a language file for each labelmessage so i want to show it in fronted previously used eval() function for it.

Comment: @sreekanth, then you need to create some map or dictionary or whatever container for translated messages and use some codes from backend to support translations. I'll say one more time - do not use eval(). ANY way of doing that would be better than calling that evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you shouldn't use `eval`. But to answer your question.The reason it says it is not a function is because its looking for a function called eval in your class. Which does not exist.

This would work for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<h2>Hello {{eval()}}`

})

export class MyComponent {
   public eval() {
     let e = eval(2*3);
     return e ;
   }
}
```

**Plunkr Example:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/YZJGPX8pjf9BNbB1F8JJ?p=preview

Again, You shouldn't use eval.

Comment: EVAL ALL THE THINGS!!

Comment: worked and thanks for this. but can u suggest an alternative for the eval()

Comment: @sreekanth, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do with eval. But maybe take a look at some of these previously asked questions.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037033/alternative-to-eval-javascript, http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323592/alternative-for-eval-in-javascript-for-expression-evaluation

Comment: i have language file consider sampl_english.js and there is a collection of variables like var X_IFL_COMMENT ="Comment"; var X_IFL_Approval_and_Coding="Approval and Coding"; when i use eval(X_IFL_Approval_and_Coding) it need to display Approval and Coding. thats my requirment

Comment: I would recommend posting that question as a separate  SO question with example.