# How to convert a string like 1/4 from a text box to numeric in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert a string like 1/4 from a text box to numeric in javascript.

```
<form>
  <input type='text' name='inputText' value='1/4'>
</form>
<script>
    var text=DOCUMENT.getElementsByName('inputText')[0].value;
</script>
```

**How to convert text to numeric?**

Comment: What do you want the value of text tobe?

Comment: At all costs, avoid `eval`. It's a dangerous function that could open your software to malicious code.
Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037033/alternative-to-eval-javascript) for alternatives to eval.

Comment: @LordAlpaca—unlikely. The user can open a console and run whatever script they want in the page anyway, or use Greasemonkey or similar. Anyone who can inject code into the *eval* part can likely inject *eval* too. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: ...until someone tricks _you_ to run _their_ code.

Comment: You could implement a shunting yard algorithm and RPN evaluation algorithm to allow users to input some arbitrary numbers/expressions, you could use eval, you could check string contents manually to see what type of number was entered, there's a few ways to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `eval()` method for this:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByName('inputText')[0].value;
document.getElementsByName('inputText2')[0].value = eval(text);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' name='inputText' value='1/4'>
  <input type='text' name='inputText2'>
</form>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

Without using `eval`, you could do this:

```js
function convertValue(value) {
  let parts = value.split("/");
  let dividend = parseFloat(parts[0]);
  let divisor = parseFloat(parts[1]);
  if (isNaN(dividend) || isNaN(divisor) || divisor === 0) {
      return "Cannot divide";
  }
  return dividend / divisor;
}

console.log(convertValue("1/4")); // 0.25
console.log(convertValue("10/2")); // 5
console.log(convertValue("-8/2")); // -4
console.log(convertValue("6/-2")); // -3
console.log(convertValue("0.5/0.25")); // 2
console.log(convertValue("a/b")); // Cannot divide
console.log(convertValue("5/0")); // Cannot divide
```

Comment: Instead of regex, I'd simply use `isNaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate it:

```js
<form>
  <input type='text' name='inputText' value='1/4'>
</form>

  <script>
    var text = eval(document.getElementsByName('inputText')[0].value);
    
    console.log(text); // returns: 0.25
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First sanitize the value

```
var fnSanitize = str => !"1/s4".match( /[^-+*/\d+]/g )
```

Above function will check if the value has anything else apart from `0-9` and `+-*\`. **You can add more operators like `()` as well.**

Now evaluate the expression

```
var evalExpression = str => fnSanitize( str ) ? eval( str ) : "";
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnSanitize = str => !str.match(/[^-+*/\d+]/g)

var evalExpression = str => fnSanitize(str) ? console.log(eval(str)) : console.log("Bad expression");

document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  evalExpression(document.querySelector("#inputText").value);
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' id='inputText' value='1/4'>
  <button id="check">Check</button>
</form>
<script>
</script>
```

Or via `Function` *constructor*

```
var evalExpression = str => fnSanitize( str ) ? new Function( "return " str ) : "";
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnSanitize = str => !str.match(/[^-+*/\d+]/g)
var evalExpression = str => fnSanitize( str ) ? console.log(new Function( "return " + str )()) : console.log("Bad expression"); 

document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  evalExpression(document.querySelector("#inputText").value);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' id='inputText' value='1/4'>
  <button id="check">Check</button>
</form>
<script>
</script>
```