# Safe/secure way to load plugins into web app

Tags: javascript, web, browser, google-chrome-extension

I have a web app that accepts JS plugins. That is, JavaScript code that someone else wrote that the user wants to load into my app.

Currently I am using eval() to evaluate their JS code into the runtime, but I know thats not secure. Is there a better method than eval() for doing this?

To be clear, the user is pointing me to a dry text file (a URL), and that JS in the file needs to come to life somehow.

There's only two ways I know of dynamically  importing a JS script:

1. Use AJAX, get the JS code, then run eval() on it.
2. Dynamically add a `<script>` tag to the DOM

The purpose of the question is to figure out if one is more secure than the other or if there is a better way than the above 2 options.

Comment: It depends on what you need to allow those plugins to do. But the only totally secure method is to run them in a [sandboxed frame](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) and provide access to your API via messaging (which can be wrapped in ES6 Proxy for elegancy).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `eval`, it's exactly the tool you'd use to make code from a text file come to life. The insecure thing is your general idea of running code written by untrusted persons in your app. You can solve your problem by making sure that everyone trusts the authors of the code - or you can tell us more details about what you need the "plugins" to do so that we can suggest a more secure solution than loading arbitrary javascript.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman As it stands, the question is much too broad to be answerable. You'd probably better post your own question where you can put a bounty and supply more details yourself, instead of reviving this months-old question by someone else.

Comment: @Bergi well now that there is a bounty I updated it to be more clear, I am still looking for a definitive answer I just put this on the backburner but would like to keep it alive

Comment: There are two ways I can think of, that will make it secure: 
*1.* Create your own programming language, which you compile into the JavaScript. That way you can be sure that only trusted things can happen. 
*2.* Use the user contributed code only in an iframe which only can communicate by a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) driven API. Both approaches are not trivial, I admit

Comment: @rakim Is there a reason why this is tagged [tag:google-chrome-extension]? Because I don't see anything relevant in the question.

Comment: @Xan yes this is primarily for a Chrome Extension

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dtao/lemming.js

Comment: @Cryptopat so lemming.js uses a web-worker to do the evaluation? I guess the web-worker is in it's own isolated scope? I think using `new Function()` would be better?

Comment: That is the whole point, the isolated scope. It is much more secure this way. This said it really depend! With `new Function()` the whole `window` object will be readable and modifiable (it is actually an xss hole). One alternative, with same downsides, make the script as a blob and inject as a full script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221144/2494754

Answer (score 4):

> Is one of these two more secure than the other?

No, they're equally bad (good) from a security perspective.

They differ in details that would lead to different approaches in making them more secure, but ultimately both do run code written by an untrusted third party in your environment, with all its privileges. It's basically a [persisted XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issue.

> Is there a better way than the above 2 options?

Many. It depends mostly on what those plugins should do in your application, who writes them and who installs (enables) them. Neither you as the application provider nor the user wants arbitrary code run havoc on the user's data. If the plugins need to access the data, you need administrative measures to ensure that only trusted code will run, like plugin code audits. At least you will need to inform your users that they must trust the plugin authors before enabling the plugin, which puts the burden on them. Also you should ensure to have [usable logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audit_trail) in case something went wrong.

If you really want to run arbitrary, untrusted code without giving it access to user data, you will want to consider sandboxing. There are various approaches that essentially do the execution in a virtual machine that the code cannot break out from.

Answer (score 4):

For Chrome Extensions I would specifically use [sandboxingEval](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval) which allows the loading of sandboxed files that can be accessed within an iframe that the extension hosts. The only message passing would be through normal iframe messaging.

For example, declare within the `manifest.json` which page to sandbox:

```
{
  ...
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "plugin.html"
    ]
    "content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' https://plugin.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Make sure the external domain is white-listed so it could be embedded. In the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) policy, `allow-scripts` is there if embedding `<scripts>` is needed.

Now within the sandboxed page `plugin.html`, do anything with the external script. In this case, the external plugin is downloaded, and passing messages back to the extension process through messaging.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://plugin.com/mohamedmansour/plugin.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Whatever my plugin contract is, lets send something back to our extension
      // that the plugin initialized.
      Plugin.do.something.here(() => {
          window.postMessage({
              name: 'CustomInitEvent',
              data: 'initializing'
          }, *);
      });

      // Listen from your extension plugin.html page some events.
      window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        var command = event.data.command;

        switch(command) {
          case 'CustomCommandA':
            event.source.postMessage({
              command: 'CustomCommandHello',
              data: 'pong command a'
            }, event.origin);
            break;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now within the popup or anywhere, just embed the `plugin.html`. In this case, popup.html looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="plugin-manager.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="theFrame" src="plugin.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then your `plugin-manager.js` is responsible of controlling plugin.

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('theFrame');
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  switch(event.name) {
    case 'CustomInitEvent':
      console.log('Plugin Initialized');
      break;

    case 'CustomCommandHello':
      console.log('Hey!');
      break;
  }
});

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
   command: 'CustomCommandA'
});

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
   command: 'CustomCommandB'
});
```

Something along those lines. If dynamic plugins is what is needed, just add query parameters to the iframe. Within `plugin.html`, just dynamically add the script element, and just call it this way:

```
<iframe id="theFrame" src="plugin.html?id=121212"></iframe>
```